# I can't do jquery droppable over event right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

[Here is the demo](https://codepen.io/k186studio/pen/xmZaJw)

I set div sketchpap, shelves, layer can droppable & draggable, and goods can only draggable, when I start drag goods, it trigger each droppable over event, i want it only trigger the over event which is contain goods div, in other words, when I drag layer it only trigger shelves over event, when I drag shelves, it only trigger sketchapd over event.

There is something different, when I first time to drag, it triggers all the droppalbe over event, but when I dragstop and try it again, it works as I wish.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
$('.goods').draggable();
$('.dropArea').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    classes:{
        "ui-droppable-hover": "cube-drop-hover"
    },
    addClasses: false,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        console.log($(this))
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
    }
})
```

Comment: It just looks like a bug, I've tried to separate all the divs but it still return every droppables name. Sorry mate, nothing to do here from what I can see

Comment: it seems like over event can't stopPropagation :-(

Comment: No, and I also checked what the target of the main event gives instead of 'this' and it's the same

Comment: the draggable target trigger the over event, when i first time drag, it seems like it init all over event once ,then it works fine... now i don't use the over event to show the hover state,only use drop event :-(